# Symfony use a dynamic variable in config file path

Tags: symfony, symfony4

For every `Program` can have one or more `Documents`, that are files uploaded with the help of the VichUploaderBundle.

I have a config file for `vich_uploader` like this:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        program_document:
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public_html/uploads/program-documents'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
```

I would like to store documents for one `Program` in one folder and not altogether. Is it possible to add a dynamic variable in `upload_destination`? Something like `%program_id%`, so that files for one program are stored in a folder with the ID of that program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to a file namer (which you already have in your config), you can also specify a directory namer (https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/namers.md#directory-namer). There are already 3 available, one of which (the `PropertyDirectoryNamer`), should solve your problem. If not, you can still write a [custom directory namer](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/directory_namer/howto/create_a_custom_directory_namer.md).

Comment: I have a bit a problem still. I try to access the parent property 'program.id' but get the error `PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "program.id" at property "id".`. I can access the properties of the child, but that is no solution.

Comment: This error actually only occurs when I remove one of the documents. For new ones there is no problem.

Comment: I figured it out, had to do with NULL values being set on the element when removing it. Thanks for the help.